# Ubuntu 21.10: Cinnamong network manager applet shows "No connection" while Internet works fine over ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, cinnamon, 21.10, applet

I don't have any problem with Internet access in Ubuntu 21.10 over ethernet, but the network manager applet in Cinnamon shows "No connection".

Is there any way to make the network manager applet to show "connected to the wired network" when my Internet connection over Ethernet is working properly?

My settings

```
 cat /etc/network/interfaces
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 allow-hotplug enp3s0
 iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

and

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

If I set managed=true and restart the network manager

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

then the applet shows "connected to the wired network". But this also allows leads to non working Internet connection after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface exists in `/etc/network/interfaces` NM won't manage it. So, just comment out the lines pertaining to `enp3s0` if you want NM to manage the connection.

Next try: `$ systemctl list-unit-files --state=disabled | grep NetworkManager` to check if it's disabled. If it is, `$ systemctl enable NetworkManager` and `systemctl NetworkManager start`

Comment: If I comment out the "allow-hotplug enp3s0" and " iface enp3s0 inet dhcp" and restart the network manager, then the network applet shows the ethernet connection correctly. But after rebooting my Internet connection stops working. Basically the situation is identical to changing "managed" to true.

Comment: Enable NM  to start automatically, as shown above.

Comment: Tried to comment out 2 lines: "allow-hotplug enp3s0" and "iface enp3s0 inet dhcp". The "systemctl list-unit-files --state=disabled | grep NetworkManager" command outputed nothing. Tried to launch "systemctl enable NetworkManager" and "systemctl start NetworkManager", but got a non-working Internet connection after rebooting.

Comment: Something is stopping NM from taking over the interface. Do you have `wicd` installed? Look through `$ ps aux | less` everything not in square brackets, and `$ dmesg | grep -i net` and `$ grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog` If you're using gnome. check if `networkmanager-gnome` is installed. Evaluate what you see. Is NM killed along the way? Not starting at boot, having trouble with the hardware interface? Can you start the connection from the NM applet. If not NM, what is trying to start the network? You can figure that out by examining the info I gave you to look at. I have faith in you!